# update specific class through query

Tags: jquery, css

I might be being completely dumb here and for that i apologise but i am a little rusty.

I am using a rating system that, as default used defaultUL and LI css styles but these affected the rest of the site, so i defined them as different class names:

ul.ratings
li.ratings

The script updates the style based on the mysql value, but for some reason i cannot seem to get the jQuery right and the stars show with no rating and don't update.

Please can someone help me make sense of this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post li').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('selected highlight')
  }).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('highlight');
  })

  $('.post li').click(function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('selected');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var oldrate = $('li.selected:last', parent).index();
    parent.data('rating', (oldrate + 1))
    data = new Object();
    data.id = parent.data('id');
    data.rating = parent.data('rating')
    $.ajax({
      url: "add_rating.php", // path of the file
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Your rating is accepted.');
      }
    });
  })

  /* reset rating */
  jQuery('.post ul').mouseout(function() {
    var rating = $(this).data('rating');
    if (rating > 0) {
      $('li:lt(' + rating + ')', this).addClass('selected');
    }
  })
})
```

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="post">

    <ul class="rating"  data-id = "<?php echo $row['fileID']; ?>" data-rating ="<?php echo $row["rating"]; ?>">
    <?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) 
    {
        $selected = "";
        if(!empty($row["rating"]) && $i<=$row["rating"]) 
        {
            $selected = "selected";
        }
    ?>
        <li class="rating <?php echo $selected; ?>">&#9733;</li>  
    <?php 
    }  
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wn7zshj2/5/

Comment: it works but affects the whole site. i want to be able to limit it to a class for this UL and LI only

Comment: So change `$('.post li')` to `$('.post li.rating')`.

Comment: i did try that but it broke it, i think it might be var oldrate setting and the line under reset rating $('li:lt(' + rating + ')', this).addClass('selected'); that are throwing it

Comment: Make sure you add `.rating` to all the selectors, like `$('.post ul.rating')`.

Comment: ok but what about the 2 lines i said were causing me the confusion? appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: Which 2 lines are causing confusion?